# Dialogflow suddenly can't extract system entities

Tags: java, dialogflow-es

Clearly, the entity extraction, which had been going well until a few minutes ago, suddenly began to fail.
Even if I enter the same sentence as the one I trained on into the console, it cannot extract the system entity. But my custom entity is extracted. What the hell's the problem? Is the system entity usage quota blocked? I'm so embarrassed. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this situation too. My agent appears to be unable to recognize any entities or parameters.

I have to export the project and import it to another region of Dialog flow service. ( from US (global) to Asia Tokyo )

Comment: Is it a region problem that the entity is not recognized? My agent is also U.S., so would it work if I change it to Tokyo? If you have solved it, I would appreciate it if you could let me know the result.